# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function while iam Embeding ruby in jquery

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
        i have a table in my main page in which left side i want to show one graph and right side i want to show second one. when iam redering both view from my index.html.erb its showing me above error and just showing me only one graph. if i show only one graph it doesn't give any error.
```

1. index.html.erb: here iam integrating my highcharts and rendering views

   ```
       <head>

           <!--Load the AJAX API-->
           <%= javascript_include_tag "highcharts"%>


       </head>
       <tr>
           <td width = "490">
           <b><%= render :partial =>  'new1' %></b>
           </td>

           <td width = "490" colspan = 2>
           <b><%= render :partial =>  'new' %></b>     

           </td>
       </tr>

      2. new1.html.erb:- its view which has to be showed left side

       <head>
       <script>
           $(function () {

           // Radialize the colors
           Highcharts.getOptions().colors = Highcharts.map(Highcharts.getOptions().colors, function (color) {
               return {
                   radialGradient: { cx: 0.5, cy: 0.3, r: 0.7 },
                   stops: [
                       [0, color],
                       [1, Highcharts.Color(color).brighten(-0.3).get('rgb')] // darken
                   ]
               };
           });

           // Build the chart
           $('#pie').highcharts({
               chart: {
                   plotBackgroundColor: null,
                   plotBorderWidth: null,
                   plotShadow: true
               },
               title: {
                   text: ''
               },
               tooltip: {
                   pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
               },
               plotOptions: {
                   pie: {
                       allowPointSelect: true,
                       cursor: 'pointer',
                       dataLabels: {
                           enabled: true,
                           format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
                           style: {
                               color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
                           },
                           connectorColor: 'silver'
                       }
                   }
               },
               series: [{
                   type: 'pie',
                   name: 'calculated',
                   data: <%= raw @result1 %>

           }]
           });
       });
       </script>
       </head>
       <div id="pie" style="width:500px; height:300px; vertical-align: top;  display: inline-block; padding: 10px;">


     3.  new.html.erb:-> its view which has to be showed right side

       <head>


       <script>
           $(function () {

           // Radialize the colors
           Highcharts.getOptions().colors = Highcharts.map(Highcharts.getOptions().colors, function (color) {
               return {
                   radialGradient: { cx: 0.5, cy: 0.3, r: 0.7 },
                   stops: [
                       [0, color],
                       [1, Highcharts.Color(color).brighten(-0.3).get('rgb')] // darken
                   ]
               };
           });

           // Build the chart
           $('#highpie').highcharts({
               chart: {
                   plotBackgroundColor: null,
                   plotBorderWidth: null,
                   plotShadow: true
               },
               title: {
                   text: ''
               },
               tooltip: {
                   pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
               },
               plotOptions: {
                   pie: {
                       allowPointSelect: true,
                       cursor: 'pointer',
                       dataLabels: {
                           enabled: true,
                           format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
                           style: {
                               color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
                           },
                           connectorColor: 'silver'
                       }
                   }
               },
               series: [{
                   type: 'pie',
                   name: 'calculated',
                   data: <%= raw @result %>

           }]
           });
       });
       </script>



       </head>
       <div id="highpie" style="width:500px; height:300px; vertical-align: top;  display: inline-block; padding: 10px;">
   ```

   conclusion:-> when iam redering both view from my index.html.erb its showing me above error and just showing me only one graph. if i show only one graph it doesn't give any error

Answer (score 0):

Wow! Your index.html.erb it is not valid, should be in the css folder, js scripts in his. You have all scattered.

Comment: hey iam using aptana studio so my highcharts.js file is in app/assets/javascripts  and my these views are in app/views. so iam integrating my files using include tag. iam saying integration is not my problem. when iam using one of them either _new.html.erb or _new.html.erb then error is occuring and only one chart is visible.

Answer (score 0):

```
in my both view i was using the same code and method of highcharts. i think
it was clashing i changed the highcharts method a little bit it worked fine for me


this is the code:->

<head>


<script>
$(function () {

    // Make monochrome colors and set them as default for all pies
    Highcharts.getOptions().plotOptions.pie.colors = (function () {
        var colors = [],
            base = Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0],
            i;

        for (i = 0; i < 10; i += 1) {
            // Start out with a darkened base color (negative brighten), and end
            // up with a much brighter color
            colors.push(Highcharts.Color(base).brighten((i - 3) / 7).get());
        }
        return colors;
    }());

    // Build the chart
    $('#highpie').highcharts({
        chart: {
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false
        },
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
          credits: {
         enabled: false
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
                    style: {
                        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'calucated',
            data: <%= raw @result %>
        }]
    });
});
</script>



</head>
<div id="highpie" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```